# Tumah from touching scalp?

Tags: halacha, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, head

Whats the reason behind the ruling that scratching or touching your scalp gives hands tumah, therefor you need to wash before discussing Torah or reciting a bracha

Comment: Sourcing your claim that you scalp imparts tumah would greatly improve your question. I know of no such rule.

Comment: I think I have cited some of the sources in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

**Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 4:18**:
"These are things require washing with water... *One who rubs his head*..."

The Mishnah Berurah, (s"k 41), says that rubbing the head is not because of a bad spirit on the hands, which is the reason for hand washing in cases such as getting up from bed or leaving a bathhouse or bathroom, rather *it is only for cleanliness purposes*, so one needn't race to wash his hands as he does to dispel a bad spirit.

**4:21**
"One should be cautious during prayer or meals not to touch the leg or thigh or places that are covered by people because they have flecks of sweat in them, *and also not to rub his head*..."

M"B, (s"k 52),  cites Yorah Deah 116 That *one must be careful of sweat because all sweat is toxic, except for sweat on the face.*

**162:8**
"If he washed one of his hands and wiped it on his head (*meaning in order to dry it, so it was not made impure, as opposed to 164:2 where he scratched his head*)"

M"B, (s"k 58), explains that he touched his hair, and even though when he touches sweat he needs to wash again as is ahead in 164, here is different because *he is not scratching in between the hairs in a place of sweat*, rather he is wiping his and above.

**164:2**
"One who is standing at a meal and remembers that he touched his leg or thigh or covered places on a person, *or that he scratched his head, and anything like this, (and in dirty places, that have sweat in them*)... He must wash again and make a blessing."

M"B, (s"k 10), again clarifies  that he must be scratching his head, not just touching his hair, recalling 162. He also, (s"k 11), edits the Shulchan Aruch's text of "...*and* in dirty places..." removing the and, because sweat is that reason for all of these things.

**So it would seem that one must wash hands after scratching the scalp because it is a place that has sweat that can be harmful to a person, which is referred to as impurity, tumah, (162:8).**